# Blogger: How can I change the header image link to anothers?

Tags: hyperlink, header, blogger

["My Blog for Testing"](https://kayblogfortesting.blogspot.jp/)

I already changed the header image , it will bring me to the homepage when I click it.

However, I would like to know how can I link to another site when I click the header image ?

Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

Go to your blogger account > Themes > Edit HTML and search for this class  **header-image-wrapper** and change attribute link.

i.e : `<a class="header-image-wrapper" href="#link">…</a>`